# Excel Color Range Conditions Macro

Tags: excel, colors, macros

I'm new to Macros and I can´t eneable it for a very simple task...

I have to assign a specific color to a cell, that contains a number, where if it's between 100-199 it must be yellow, 200-299 orange and 300-399 red, like the image attached. The idea is to make this automatic for dynamic analisys...

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Matt

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a native worksheet formula is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck!  No VBA needed... just use conditional formatting to set this up :)

[image]